# pandas subtract two sets of data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out why if I subtract two sets of data it gives me NaN errors. I want to do an element-by-element subtraction and I have successfully extracted two separate sets but when I try to do anything with it, it keeps giving me NaN errors

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'vc_test.csv'
headings = 'injection', 'treatment','filename', 'l0', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'filename', 'r0', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3'

#import data
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=headings)




#convert values to floats
df['l0'] = df['l0'].astype(float)
df['l1'] = df['l1'].astype(float)
df['l2'] = df['l2'].astype(float)
df['l3'] = df['l3'].astype(float)
df['r0'] = df['r0'].astype(float)
df['r1'] = df['r1'].astype(float)
df['r2'] = df['r2'].astype(float)
df['r3'] = df['r3'].astype(float)

#group by injection so you have 2 subgroups
df.groupby(['injection'])

#subtract and assign to a different array to normalize data to baseline
df_os, df_od = df[['l1','l2','l3']].sub(df['l0'], axis=0), df[['r1','r2','r3']].sub(df['r0'], axis=0)

print df_os
print df_od

ioc = df_os - df_od
print ioc
```

I have also tried df.sub() but it didn't work. Please help...

Comment: You have to explain by showing what *didn't work* means, also this line `df.groupby(['injection'])` does nothing

Comment: Like @EdChum wrote: please show what the *didn't work* part looks like. For example, show the result of `sub()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with column names - you need equal column names in both substracted `DataFrames`. Also for creating `DataFrames` you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
import pandas as pd
import io


temp=u"""
1,a1453905960,a,95.4500,95.0900,95.0980,433810,s,95.4500,95.0900,95.0980,433810
1,a1453906020,b,95.4700,94.9500,95.4500,934980,d,85.4520,94.100,95.7980,433810
2,a1453906080,f,95.1000,94.8700,95.0900,791657,e,95.4500,934980,9.4400,85.4520
2,a1453906140,c,4.0300,94.7000,94.9620,763531,w,95.1000,94.8700,95.0900,791657
2,a1453906200,f,95.0300,94.8200,94.8918,501298,r,95.1000,94.8700,95.0900,791657"""

headings =[ 'injection', 'treatment','filename', 'l0', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'filename', 'r0', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3']

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=headings)
print df
   injection    treatment filename     l0     l1       l2      l3 filename  \
0          1  a1453905960        s  95.45  95.09  95.0980  433810        s   
1          1  a1453906020        d  95.47  94.95  95.4500  934980        d   
2          2  a1453906080        e  95.10  94.87  95.0900  791657        e   
3          2  a1453906140        w   4.03  94.70  94.9620  763531        w   
4          2  a1453906200        r  95.03  94.82  94.8918  501298        r   

       r0         r1      r2          r3  
0  95.450      95.09  95.098  433810.000  
1  85.452      94.10  95.798  433810.000  
2  95.450  934980.00   9.440      85.452  
3  95.100      94.87  95.090  791657.000  
4  95.100      94.87  95.090  791657.000
```

```
#convert values to floats
df[['l0','l1','l2','l3','r0','r1','r2','r3']] = df[['l0','l1','l2','l3','r0','r1','r2','r3']].astype(float)


#select data by column injection to 2 new dataframes by boolean indexing
df_os = df[df['injection'] == 1]
#print df_os 

df_od = df[df['injection'] == 2]
#print df_od

#subtract and assign to a different array to normalize data to baseline
df_os, df_od = df[['l1','l2','l3']].sub(df['l0'], axis=0), df[['r1','r2','r3']].sub(df['r0'], axis=0)
```

```
print df_os
      l1       l2         l3
0  -0.36  -0.3520  433714.55
1  -0.52  -0.0200  934884.53
2  -0.23  -0.0100  791561.90
3  90.67  90.9320  763526.97
4  -0.21  -0.1382  501202.97

print df_od
           r1      r2          r3
0      -0.360  -0.352  433714.550
1       8.648  10.346  433724.548
2  934884.550 -86.010      -9.998
3      -0.230  -0.010  791561.900
4      -0.230  -0.010  791561.900

#set column names in df_od by df_os
df_od.columns = df_os.columns
ioc = df_os - df_od
print ioc
           l1       l2          l3
0       0.000   0.0000       0.000
1      -9.168 -10.3660  501159.982
2 -934884.780  86.0000  791571.898
3      90.900  90.9420  -28034.930
4       0.020  -0.1282 -290358.930

ioc = df_os.sub(df_od)
print ioc
           l1       l2          l3
0       0.000   0.0000       0.000
1      -9.168 -10.3660  501159.982
2 -934884.780  86.0000  791571.898
3      90.900  90.9420  -28034.930
4       0.020  -0.1282 -290358.930
```

Or you can convert `DataFrames` to `numpy arrays` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then substract:

```
ioc = df_os.values - df_od.values
print ioc
[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -9.16800000e+00  -1.03660000e+01   5.01159982e+05]
 [ -9.34884780e+05   8.60000000e+01   7.91571898e+05]
 [  9.09000000e+01   9.09420000e+01  -2.80349300e+04]
 [  2.00000000e-02  -1.28200000e-01  -2.90358930e+05]]

print pd.DataFrame(ioc, columns=['a','b','c'])
            a        b           c
0       0.000   0.0000       0.000
1      -9.168 -10.3660  501159.982
2 -934884.780  86.0000  791571.898
3      90.900  90.9420  -28034.930
4       0.020  -0.1282 -290358.930
```